# Slideshow image link not working in IE9

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I'm using a Nivo Slider on the homepage of my [website](http://belfurniture.com/), but in IE9, the slide links are not working (they work in all other modern browsers).

What I've done so far (that haven't worked):

- Increased the z-index of the link
- Removed the link class name to make sure nivo slider CSS is not causing it

Any idea what might the issue be?

Comment: The link provided for your website load only page blank

Comment: It shouldn't be, can you try one more time please.

Comment: nothinkg, only page blank

Comment: Have you tried the following? Do you have a sample of your jquery code?

http://weeblyforums.com/topic/nivo-slider-on-ie9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue sometime back. What fixed it for me was assigin `important` to specfic CSS declarations as shown below:

```
.theme-default .nivoSlider a, 
.theme-default .nivoSlider img {
display: block !important;
}
```